# Glassfish security realm for each application

Tags: security, glassfish

I have deployed two applications onto the glassfish server, each of which uses its own security realm (file, jdbc). The problem is that the glassfish allows only one default realm to be set which results in only one application to be functional at a time. I'm a newbie with the glassfish so I might be missing something fundamental or should approach this problem differently (do I need a separate domain for each of mine applications to be able to set the security with specific realm?).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create more file Realms in the same GlassFish domain, you simply have to specify a new file name for the keyfile storing the users / passwords information. You can follow this [tutorial](http://www.developinjava.com/securing-a-web-application-on-glassfish-using-jaas.html) if you wish.

Concerning the other part of the question, you can also consider to use a [LDAP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2435/ggkuk.html#gkbjp) server, which is a scalable and more general solution, because it can be used also by other applications inside the same firm. You can use [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/) or [OpenDJ](http://www.forgerock.com/opendj.html) for example, and use [JNDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/) API for letting your applications access the LDAP realm.

[Here](http://www.cris.com/~adhawan/tutorial/) you can find a JNDI and OpenLDAP Tutorial, but you can easily find other tutorials around on the subject.

Comment: Thanks perissf, I can see where you coming from. It is definitely next thing I will learn to implement. I found what I was looking for from my tutor at the end. Bottom line is that I got confused with GF default security realm setting and thought of it as using a 'single' realm for all applications. That's not the case however. You can set as many realms as you like and then reference them from within the app's web.xml by <realm-name>realm_name</realm-name> tags.

Comment: Be welcome. If you found that the answer was helpful, you can mark it as accepted and / or vote it.